# Django Admin - suppress or alter inlines that aren't relevant for an object

Tags: django-forms, django-admin

I have a model with question objects defined by their answer_type.  One of the available types is 'Choice' as in, multiple choice.  The Choice objects are a separate class with a foreign key of question.

This structure means Choices can be created for a question and then the question can be converted to another type without the Choices being deleted.  It also means that in the Admin screen, the ChoiceInline always shows up for every question.

To remove the ChoiceInline when it isn't wanted, I've overridden get_formsets_with_inlines(), adapting [this example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines)

```
def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):        
    for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):  
       if obj.answer_type == "CH" and isinstance(inline, ChoiceInline):  # Choices available on a choice question
           yield inline.get_formset(request,obj), inline
       elif obj.answer_type != "CH" and isinstance(inline, ChoiceInline):  # Choices exist on a non-choice question
           continue
       else:
           yield inline.get_formset(request,obj), inline  # Other inlines
```

This fails validation if Choices exist in the database for a non-choice question.  I want to tolerate this inconsistency because people might naturally vacillate while they are building their question set, between choices or short answers, for example.

How do I create an appropriate inline for this situation? I set out to remove it completely but a 'HiddenChoiceInline' or even a 'RedChoiceInline' that shows there's an inconsistency might suit me - but then how to efficiently yield them in get_formsets_with_inlines() is a problem. Can I generate two or more variant ChoiceInlines for the same question?  I'm going to try that now, but if a smart person who knows things could help that would be terrific.

Answer (score 0):

A resolution I'm happy with, after learning a lot - hope this turns out to be useful to someone:

1. over-ride 'get_formsets_with_inlines' just a little, following the example from the docs shown above.  This simply checks if the inline is a set of choices for a non-choice question, and if so:

   - adds 'inconsistent' to the list of 'classes' (css classes) along with 'collapse'.
   - sets the fields to 'read-only' to discourage people from editing choices that can't be presented. The 'delete' checkbox still works.

     def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
     for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
        if obj.answer_type == "CH" and isinstance(inline, ChoiceInline):  # Choices available on a choice question
            inline.formfield_overrides = { models.CharField : {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'100',})}, } 
            yield inline.get_formset(request,obj), inline
        elif obj.answer_type != "CH" and isinstance(inline, ChoiceInline):
            inline.formfield_overrides = { models.CharField : {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'100','readonly': True, })}, }
            inline.classes = ['collapse', 'inconsistent',]
            yield inline.get_formset(request,obj), inline
        else:
            yield inline.get_formset(request,obj), inline  # Other inlines exist
2. modify the inner class 'Media' for inlines that must visually show results of this test with some bespoke css.

   class ChoiceInline(text_areaTabInline):
       model = Choice
       fk_name = 'question'
       extra = 0
       max_num = 25
       class Media:
           css = {
                  'all': ("admin/admin_styles.css",) 
                   }
3. Add an 'admin' directory under 'static' and create admin_styles.css

The style I added uses a combinator to select any h2 inside a fieldset classed as 'inconsistent':

```
fieldset.inconsistent > h2 { color:Tomato; border:5px solid Tomato;} 
fieldset.inconsistent > h2:after {content:' Not currently a choice question.';}
```

It is suitably lairy, I'm pretty happy, except for how long it took me.  Lots to learn.

(my ChoiceInline objects always have class = ['collapse'] set)